# Differences between IE5 and IE8 Quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I have a website that was programmed several years back and optimized for IE5/6. Now when it displays in IE8 some pages don't display right. I've confirmed that IE8 is displaying the page in Quirks mode (not Standards mode).

I'm told that Quirks mode in IE5/6 is different from Quirks mode in IE8.

**Is there any site that lists the differences between how IE8 and IE6 display Quirks mode?**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't hear about site, but maybe program [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) will help you

Answer (score -1):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Comment: Quirks mode renders like [IE5.50](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), which is different than [IE5.00](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512) in terms of [CSS parsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms531201) and [behaviors](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301531).